# Fetch data from mysql and display data in ExpandableListView in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I have visited the link with the same topic but none of em answer my question. I don't want to make a custom Expandable list view just using the simple expandable list view. I have been successfully able to fetch data from mysql database and verified all the values that are being retrieved using toast message and also tested the php script using postman.
Now I want to display the fetched values in ExpandableListView.
This is the list_child.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am using a function to fetch the values from database and I am getting the values, but I am unable to print those values in ExpandableListView. This function prepare the expandable list view

```
private void ListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();

    //Adding header to expandable list view
    listDataHeader.add("ABC");
    listDataHeader.add("DEF");

    //Adding child data
    List<String> abc = new ArrayList<>();
    abc.add(fetchAbc());
    List<String> def = new ArrayList<>();
    def.add(fetchDef());


    //Header child data
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(0),abc);
    listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1),def);
}
    private String fetchAbc() {

    return ("first name : \t"+Name+"\nEmail : \t"+email);
}

private String fetchDef() {

    return ("Id : \t"+id);
}
```

In the expandable list view I am getting the child view like first name, email and Id return from the above functions. But not the values. This is ExpandableListAdapter class file

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context _context;
    private List<String> _listDataHeader;
    private HashMap<String,List<String>> _listDataChild;
    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                                 HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData) {
        this._context = context;
        this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this._listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        }

        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
                .size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this._listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.header);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Expandable Listview with dynamic data in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523257/expandable-listview-with-dynamic-data-in-android)

Comment: I checked the link and also the answer, you should notice that the OP has not accepted the answer. And I don't want to create a custom Expandable list view i just want to achieve this with the simple one

Answer (score 0):

```
private void prepareListData() {
    listDataHeader = new ArrayList<String>();
    listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
    url = ip.ip+"loadcourse.php";
    StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {



                    try {
                        JSONArray data = new JSONArray(response);
                        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {


                            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                            one = c.getString("dname").split(",");
                            two = c.getString("course_name");
                            listDataHeader.add(String.valueOf(one[0]));


                            JSONArray dt= new JSONArray(two.toString());
                            List<String> nowShowing  = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < dt.length(); j++) {


                                JSONObject d = dt.getJSONObject(j);

                                three = d.getString("course").split(",");

                                nowShowing.add(String.valueOf(three[0]));


                            }
                            listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(i), nowShowing); 










                        }




                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    // response
                    Log.d("Response", response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    // error
                    Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
                }
            }
    ) {
       @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

           params.put("cid",ip.id);
           return params;
        }
    };
    queue.add(postRequest);
```